# Root of quadratic equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the equation $x^2-a\cdot y^2-b=0$ with $a$ positive and $b$ positive.

It seems that if the square root of a+b is an integer, there are automatically integer solutions for the equation.

But what about if the square root of a+b isn't an integer? It depends:
for example, $x^2-2\cdot y^2-4=0$ has a solution, but $x^2-2\cdot y^2-3=0$ has no solutions.

Did I get it right and could someone provide a more precise explanation please?

Comment: This looks like a generalized Pell equation

Comment: The solution is easy when $a$ is a perfect square.

Comment: There are obviously solutions when $b=u^2-av^2$, for any $a,u,v$.

Answer (score 3):

The set of solutions of $x^2 - 2 y^2 = k$ is invariant under the linear mapping
$$ M: \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr} \to \pmatrix{3 x + 4 y\cr 2 x + 3 y\cr}$$ and so is the set of integer solutions.

If $k > 0$, the hyperbola $x^2 - 2 y^2 = k$ has two branches, one in the right half plane and in the left, and the images under positive and negative integer powers of $M$ of the piece of the curve for $x > 0, \, -\sqrt{k/2} \le y \le \sqrt{k/2}$ cover the right branch.
Thus there is an integer solution if and only if there is an integer solution with $ |y| \le \sqrt{k/2}$ (by symmetry we can consider $0 \le y \le \sqrt{k/2}$).

If $k < 0$, the branches are in the upper and lower half planes, and we similarly consider the images of the piece of the curve for $y > 0,\,  -\sqrt{-k} \le x \le \sqrt{-k}$.